# Pregunta sobre Array en ejercicio de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, snippets

El ejercicio consiste en una cafeteria en la cual el cafe vale $5. Al comienzo del dia la cafeteria tiene 0 monedas. Los clientes solo pueden pagar con monedas de 5, 10 o 15. Se me pide que indique cantidad de clientes y monedas con las que pagan. El cajero da el vuelto siempre con la moneda más grande primero, si tiene disponible (ejemplo: si paga con $15, da el vuelto de $10 si tiene moneda de $10 o 2 de $5, si no tiene de $10).
Si el cajero no tiene vuelto para darle, no se vende ese café y el cliente se va sin atención.
Al final debo indicar con alert "SE ATENDIERON A TODOS" o "NO SE ATENDIERON A TODOS".

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora. Nose como acceder al array para descontar las monedas a medida que se usen.

```
var cantidadClientes = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cantidad de clientes"));{

  let monedas = [];

  while(true){
      let input = prompt("Valor Moneda");
      //Aprieto cancelar cuando no haya mas valores de moendas para agregar
      if(input === null || input === "c"){
          break;
      }
      monedas.push(Number(input));
      console.log(monedas)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta un arreglo para las monedas, se pueden ir procesando conforme se van ingresando, te dejo un ejemplo de clientes que pagan con monedas de 5 y 10:

```js
// variable para guardar la cantidad de clientes que 
// llegaran a comprar
let cantidadDeClientes = parseInt(prompt("ingrese la cantidad de clientes"));

let clientesAtendidos = 0;

let monedasDe5 = 0;
let monedasDe10 = 0;
let monedasDe15 = 0;

// ciclo para pedir el ingreso de las monedas de cada cliente
// y procesar la venta
for( i = 1; i <= cantidadDeClientes; i++){
   
   // en la variable moneda se guarda la moneda con la que el cliente
   // está pagando
   let moneda = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese valor de moneda del cliente ${i}`));
   
  
  // aquí se procesa la venta
  
  switch(moneda){
    // si el valor de la moneda es 5 entonces la venta se hace
    case 5:
       // agregamos una moneda de 5
       monedasDe5 += 1;
       // se incrementa la cuenta de clientes atendidos
       clientesAtendidos++;
       break;
       
     case 10:
      // si paga con moneda de 10 pero no hay al menos una 
      // moneda de 5 para dar cambio entonces no se puede vender
      // asi que continuamos con el siguiente cliente
      if(monedasDe5  == 0 ) continue;
      
      // agregamos una moneda de 10
      monedasDe10++;
      // descontamos una moneda de 5 para dar cambio
      monedasDe5--;
      // se incrementa la cuenta de clientes atendidos
      clientesAtendidos++;
      
      break;
      
      
     
  }
   

}

console.log(`clientes atendidos: ${clientesAtendidos} de ${cantidadDeClientes}`)
```